# Match and list column terms in R from .xlsx

Tags: r, excel

Hi I am quite new to R and i need to match terms from .xlsx columns to get a list of matched data between three .xlsx. The data in files is like this:

From one.xlsx:

```
OneID   NameOne
ACR019  Acropectoral Syndrome
ACR020  Acropectorovertebral
GNT015  Genital Dwarfism
ACR023  Acral Dysostosis Dyserythropoiesis Syndrome
```

From two.xlsx:

```
TwoID   TwoName
607907  DERMATOFIBROSARCOMA PROTUBERANS
304730  DERMOIDS OF CORNEA
605967  ACROPECTORAL SYNDROME
102510  ACROPECTOROVERTEBRAL
```

From three.xlsx:

```
ThreeID ThreeName
OM85203 Acropectoral syndrome
OM67092 Dermoids cornea
OM76580 Acardia
OM45632 Hypertryptophanemia
```

And the final result file in .xlsx must look like this:

```
OneID  NameOne                TwoID  TwoName                 ThreeID ThreeName
ACR019 Acropectoral Syndrome  605967 ACROPECTORAL SYNDROME   OM85203 Acropectoral syndrome
ACR020 Acropectorovertebral   102510 ACROPECTOROVERTEBRAL    -
-                             304730  DERMOIDS OF CORNEA     OM67092 Dermoids cornea
```

Thank you very much, any suggestion or help to code this will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this: due your only common fields are names in various dataset, we have to use them, as key to connect the various .xlsx, after make some small transformations (generally imho it's not a great idea use descriptions as key, but we could not do different in this case), using the `merge()` function.


After import the three MSExcel files, you can do:

```
# first your data (fake)
one <- data.frame(OneID=c('ACR019','ACR020','GNT015','ACR023'),
                      NameOne = c('Acropectoral Syndrome','Acropectorovertebral','Genital Dwarfism','Acral Dysostosis Dyserythropoiesis Syndrome'))

two <- data.frame(OneID=c('A607907','304730','605967','102510'),
                       NameTwo = c('DERMATOFIBROSARCOMA PROTUBERANS','DERMOIDS OF CORNEA','ACROPECTORAL SYNDROME','ACROPECTOROVERTEBRAL'))


three <-data.frame(OneID=c('OM85203','OM67092','OM76580','OM45632'),
                       NameThree = c('Acropectoral syndrome','Dermoids cornea','Acardia','Hypertryptophanemia'))

# then, to have uniques keys, you can put all of them as upper cases to create ids:
    one$ID <- toupper(one$NameOne)
    two$ID <- toupper(two$NameTwo)
    three$ID <- toupper(three$NameThree)

# after that, you can merge the dataframes:    
merged <- merge(merge(one,two, by ='ID', all = TRUE),three, by ='ID', all = TRUE)

#lastly, you give them the names you want (to columns)    
colnames(merged) <- c('ID', 'OneID','NameOne','TwoID','NameTwo','ThreeID','NameThree')

# here the results   
merged

> merged
                                           ID  OneID                                     NameOne   TwoID                         NameTwo
1                                     ACARDIA   <NA>                                        <NA>    <NA>                            <NA>
2 ACRAL DYSOSTOSIS DYSERYTHROPOIESIS SYNDROME ACR023 Acral Dysostosis Dyserythropoiesis Syndrome    <NA>                            <NA>
3                       ACROPECTORAL SYNDROME ACR019                       Acropectoral Syndrome  605967           ACROPECTORAL SYNDROME
4                        ACROPECTOROVERTEBRAL ACR020                        Acropectorovertebral  102510            ACROPECTOROVERTEBRAL
5             DERMATOFIBROSARCOMA PROTUBERANS   <NA>                                        <NA> A607907 DERMATOFIBROSARCOMA PROTUBERANS
6                             DERMOIDS CORNEA   <NA>                                        <NA>    <NA>                            <NA>
7                          DERMOIDS OF CORNEA   <NA>                                        <NA>  304730              DERMOIDS OF CORNEA
8                            GENITAL DWARFISM GNT015                            Genital Dwarfism    <NA>                            <NA>
9                         HYPERTRYPTOPHANEMIA   <NA>                                        <NA>    <NA>                            <NA>
  ThreeID             NameThree
1 OM76580               Acardia
2    <NA>                  <NA>
3 OM85203 Acropectoral syndrome
4    <NA>                  <NA>
5    <NA>                  <NA>
6 OM67092       Dermoids cornea
7    <NA>                  <NA>
8    <NA>                  <NA>
9 OM45632   Hypertryptophanemia
```

Comment: Oh this is so helpful but still have one problem, as you can see in result you have a duplicate, in line 6 and 7 "dermoids cornea" and "dermoids of cornea" is same thing but filtering by exactly ID returs some duplicates. Any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: This is going to be always in that way, because if an id is different from another id, they are not going to match. Or you have unique ids (but you don't except description), or in data entry you should be consistent (same things, same names), or you have to have write in R that "dermoids cornea" and "dermoids of cornea"  are equal. We read the two things equal, but for a machine they are different, due different characters. As proof, if you remove the 'of', you'll not notice the problem.